# How to add ASP DropDown values through javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, drop-down-menu

I am using a asp drop down list. According to my requirement I need to set the values of that drop down list through external java script file. How is it possible? I will not use `document` object to get the drop down Id.

Comment: what do you mean by asp drop down list? are you using asp.net mvc?

Comment: Remember that in all likelihood, ASP.NET will not detect the new options correctly on a postback – `listControl.Items` should only contain items you add in code-behind or that are restored from ViewState. You'll have to figure out which items are selected some other way. (E.g. directly from the HTTP request.)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "I will not use document object to get the drop down Id."? And are you using jQuery or not? That is, is it okay for the answer to be jQuery based or would you prefer plain Javascript?

Comment: @Inerdial It is OK for me to use the `J query` code to implement the above functionality. Please provide me the sample code snippet.That will help me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SandeepGB Thanks for your response. I am using `C#` language for coding and in the page I am using `aspx controls`. Please provide the sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can set up the list of option values as a js array then you can use jQuery's [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)  method to build the dropdown like this

**HTML**

```
​<select id="drop"></select>​
```

**JQuery**

```
var values = ['test1','test2','test3','test4','test5','test6'​];

​$.each(values,function(i,val){
   $('<option />').text(val).val(val).appendTo('#drop');
});​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/sFVgf/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i am using ASP dropdown list. Please provide me the code snippet for the corresponding. Thanks in advance.